# How to change a child view of a ListView, in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` which works with a custom adapter, and has two `ImageView`'s and one `TextView` in each row. 
I want to handle the click on one of the two `ImageView`'s by changing its `drawable`.

I have tried the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` class 
and have also tried to add a specific `OnClickListener` on the `ImageView` in the adapter class 
and the listening is working there, but it can not update the `drawable` of the `ImageView`.

So how I can do this ?

This is the code inside my `adapter.getView()` method :

```
    holder.getInfos().setText(posts.get(position).toString());
    holder.getPp().setProfileId(posts.get(position).getProfile());
    holder.getLike().setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_like_inactive);

    holder.getLike().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            postLiked = !postLiked; holder.getLike().setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_like);

        }
    });
```

Comment: did you call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: and please provide us your code so i could help you better if it didn't work

Comment: Yes, i did, still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @has19 commented. On your `onClick` don't change the drawable of the `ImageView` directly, but change the data upon which you choose the drawable in your adapter's `getView`. Then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter after the click.

Sample pseudo-code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final MyObject myObject = getItem(position);

    ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImageViewId);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myObject.setImageSelectionCriteria(someCriteria);
            MyAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    if(myObject.getImageSelectionCriteria().equals(someCriteria)) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_drawable);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_other_drawable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome !!!, thank you man. This solved my problem. Actually, it is as you said "onClick don't change the drawable of the ImageView directly".